# Python sax parser query for nested XML and Dynamic variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, sax

I have some queries around Python SAX parser and I am very new to it.

I know its event driven means based on open and end tag events it work.

**Below is my queries:**

1. In "def characters" section where we read the text part of the XML, how do we assign variable name and value dynamically?
   Currently its like below:

> def characters(self, content):
>       content=content.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")
>       if self.CurrentData == "fileId":
>           self.fileId += content
>       elif self.CurrentData == "fileDate":
>           self.fileDate += content

```
    so on ..... 
wanted self.<tagname> variable to be dynamic.
```

2. How to handle nested XML position same in a python object using SAX? In case below is XML I want Object to hold like below:

   **Sample XML:**

> ```
>   <test>      <dept1>             <emp1>
>           <name>Test User</name>
>           <phoneNumber>
>               <home>12121</home>
>               <mobile>234234<mobile>
>           </phoneNumber>          </emp1>         <dept1>         <dept2>
>           <name>Test User</name>
>           <phoneNumber>
>               <home>12121</home>
>               <mobile>234234<mobile>
>           </phoneNumber>          </emp1>         <dept2>     </test>
> ```

**Object**

> ```
> {'test':      {
>     'dept1':{'name':'Test User','phoneNumber':{'home':'12121','mobile':234234}},
>     'dept2':{'name':'Test User','phoneNumber':{'home':'12121','mobile':234234}}       }   }
> ```